# Преобразовать массивы в объекты js

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема.
Есть массив

```
const parent = [
    ['a', 1, 2, 3],
    ['b', 4, 5, 6],
    ['c', 7, 8, 9, 10],
    ['d', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
]
```

Необходимо преобразовать его в:

```
const secondArr = [
    {a: 1, b: 4, c: 7, d: 11},
    {a: 2, b: 5, c: 8, d: 12},
    {a: 3, b: 6, c: 9, d: 13},
    {a: null, b: null, c: 10, d: 14},
    {a: null, b: null, c: null, d: 15}
]
```

Как можно проще сделать это преобразование?

Comment: какие только проблемы и задачи люди себе не выдумавают. Интересно, какую в целом задачу ты решаешь, что потом надо заниматься таким непонятным извратом?

Comment: Такой объект невозможен, потому что любой объект должен состоять из ключей и значений, а у `obj` нет ключей

Comment: поправил ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const parent = [
  ['a', 1, 2, 3],
  ['b', 4, 5, 6],
  ['c', 7, 8, 9, 10],
  ['d', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
];

function transform(array) {
  let max = 0;
  for (let key in array) {
    max = Math.max(array[key].length - 1, max);
  }
  let obj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    obj[i] = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      obj[i][array[j][0]] = (array[j][i + 1] !== undefined ? array[j][i + 1] : null);
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(transform(parent));
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный вариант решения со встроенными функциями массивов:

```
    const parent = [
    ['a', 1, 2, 3],
    ['b', 4, 5, 6],
    ['c', 7, 8, 9, 10],
    ['d', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
]
function transform(array) {
    var i,nelems,keys,vals=[],tgt=[];
    nelems = array.reduce(function (a,b) {return a.length > b.length ? a.length-1:b.length-1;}, 0);
    keys = array.map(function (a) {return a[0]});
   for (i = 0;i<nelems;i++) {
       ncol = i+1;
       vals[i] = array.map(function(a){return a[ncol]?a[ncol]:null}); 
   }
   vals.forEach(function (item,ns) {
    tgt[ns] = {};
    item.map(function(q,i){tgt[ns][keys[i]] = q;});
   });
   return tgt;
}

console.log(transform(parent));
```